# Class objects are passed by value?

Tags: php, variables, scope

I'm new to PHP. I'll like to check the scope of the variables I've used. In particular `$model`.

```
$model = new LoginModel();
$controller = new LoginController($model);
$view = new LoginView($controller, $model);
```

Attached below are codes I have written for logging in. A user would visit the page via `GET /login.php` then submits the form to `POST /login.php?action=login`. In this process the `LoginModel` is updated accordingly by `LoginController`.

I would like to use the `$model` that I have updated in later parts of the execution of the page. However, I noticed that `$model` is "reset" once the call returns from `LoginController.login()`.
I'm not sure if it is because `$model` was passed by value in my case. Or if there is something else I'm doing wrong but I'm not aware of. Can anyone enlighten me on this?

```
<?php
class LoginModel {
    public $username = "";
    public $password = "";
    public $message = "";
    public $loginSuccess = false;

    public function __construct() {

    }
}

class LoginView {
    private $model;
    private $controller;

    public function __construct($controller, $model) {
        $this->controller = $controller;
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function getUsernameField() {
        return $this->makeInput("text", "username", "");
    }

    public function getPasswordField() {
        return $this->makeInput("password", "password", "");
    }

    private function makeInput($type, $name, $value) {
        $html = "<input type=\"$type\" name=\"$name\" value=\"$value\" />";
        return $html;
    }
}

class LoginController {
    const HOME_URL = "http://localhost/";
    private $model;

    public function __construct($model) {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function login() {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if ($username === $password) { 
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

            $model->username = $username;
            $model->password = "";
            $model->message = "Hello, $username!";
            $model->loginSuccess = true;

            header("Refresh: 3; URL=" + LoginController::HOME_URL);
        } else {
            $model->message = "Sorry, you have entered an invalid username-password pair.";
            $model->loginSuccess = false;
        }
    }

    public function handleHttpPost() {
        if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
            if ($_GET['action'] === 'login') {
                $this->login();
            }
        } else {
            // invalid request.
            http_response_code(400);
            die();
        }
    }

    public function handleHttpGet() {
        if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
            // request for controller action
            // No controller actions for HTTP GET
        } else {
            // display login page
        }
    }

    public function redirectToHome() {
        header("Location: " + LoginController::HOME_URL);
        die();
    }
}


$model = new LoginModel();
$controller = new LoginController($model);
$view = new LoginView($controller, $model);

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $controller->redirectToHome();
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $controller->handleHttpPost();
} else if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
    $controller->handleHttpGet();
}

?>

<html>

    <body>
        <?php if ($model->loginSuccess) { ?>
            <h1>Login Successful, Redirecting...</h1>
            <p><?= $model->message; ?></p>
        <?php
        } else { ?>
            <form action="login.php?action=login" method="POST">
                Username: <br />
                <?php echo $view->getUsernameField(); ?> <br/><br/>
                Password: <br />
                <?php echo $view->getPasswordField(); ?><br/><br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Log In"/>
            </form>
            <p><?= $model->message; ?></p>
        <?php
        }?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Update: Solved. Thanks @RiggsFolly for pointing it out.**

Well, I got the wrong`$model`.

```
public function login() {
    ....
    $model->username = $username; //referenced the wrong variable
    $this->model->username = $username //should have done this.
}
```

**Also, Thanks @Fred -ii-**
(sorry I left you out)

```
public function login() {
    ....
    header("Refresh: 3; URL=" + LoginController::HOME_URL); //not the right way to concat
    header("Refresh: 3; URL=" . LoginController::HOME_URL); //should have been this.
}
```

Comment: For one thing, `header("Refresh: 3; URL=" + LoginController::HOME_URL);` you're trying to concatenate with a `+` which in PHP it's a dot that needs to be used. You seem to be coming from a C background, hence the error.

Comment: Try using a correct reference to what you are trying to set a value into EG `$this->model->username = $username;`

Comment: Everthing in php is at first passed by reference (objects, array, string), but at any change the variable will copied for real, only object  will still be a reference. So if you want a reference from an string or other than object, the function/method must have the ref. prefix like `function xyz($noref,&$ref);`

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Didn't notice that. Thanks, will correct it.

Comment: If you have xdebug enabled you can test and check for yourself via `xdebug_debug_zval()` what kind of ref or variable you have. http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php

Comment: But like has been said above. Once you refresh the page, anything you did in this script is lost as the new refreshed page will start from scratch again knowing nothing of what you did before, unless you save it in a session i.e. STATELESS

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions: So if I need to have them be passed by reference, then all functions need to use <code>&$ref</code>. Can I say that functions accepting no parameters <code>function foo()</code> can never change object attributes because changing it in <code>foo()</code> will create a new copy of the object itself? And thanks for the useful tip for XDebug!

Comment: In a simplified model, everything in PHP is passed by value. The objects seem to be passed by reference but this is actually not true. Internally, PHP keeps the objects in a list and uses handles to identify them. These handles are the values that are passed (by value, i.e. copies) when objects are assigned, passed as arguments or returned from functions. The bottom line is: the objects behave like they are always passed by reference. If you want to make a copy of an object you have to [`clone`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Yes, i'm aware that the pages are stateless. Let me try your suggestion. I'll update you in a bit.

Comment: @RiggsFolly: You're right on this one. I unknowingly used the wrong `$model` variable.

Comment: @clone `passed by value` sounds like you need more memory when passing stuff around, and objects must have  its own uniq hash then. Dont thing that it works like that. Basicly a reference is a pointer to memory address[area], or not?

Comment: @xefrog How will a function like `func()` with no parameters in the declaration, handle a object that comes from outside?!? And `objects` are always references until you clone an object, so any manipulation is on the original object.

Comment: @xefrog *"Update: Solved. Thanks @ RiggsFolly for pointing it out."* - 90% of it, *lol!* - [Let's not forget about 'ol Fred now...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42722369/class-objects-are-passed-by-value#comment72564576_42722369) ;-) Error reporting would have been of help here and would have thrown something about it.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions: My bad. Missed out some information. I meant `foo()` using an attribute from the same class as itself. In my case making changes to `$model` with `login()` not accepting any parameters. Then `$model` will be a independent copy of itself in `login()`?

Comment: a `copy` will only be exists of an object after you do `$newobj = (clone)$oldObj;` there is no other way to make a copy of an object in php.

Comment: @xefrog *"Also, Thanks @ Fred -ii- (sorry I left you out)"* - Ahh... thanks :-) Glad to see you got your solution. I'd invite RIggs to also post an answer, seeing there is one posted below.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions: Alright :) Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

**Only a simple statement**

for `because $model was passed by value`

We have an object in `$model` and pass it to the constructor

`$controller = new LoginController($model);`

it will be bound as reference to 
`$controller->model = $model`.

Now we have an reference of the model in the controller.

If you know do (if possible, lets say yes) this: `unset($controller->model);`

you dont have killed the `$model` instance, you have just removed the reference to `$model` that was set before.

But now the other way around:

```
#create an object
$model = new stdClass();

#create the holder
$b=new stdClass();
#bind the first obj
$b->model=$model;

#unset the first object
$model=null;
unset($model);

#oooh, what it is still there
print_r($b->model);
```

Here we have not `unset($model)` for real, because php knows that the instance is used later. So php goes and kills the reference between `$model` and the real object, but not the reference between `$b->model` and the real object.
In a way the reference has moved vom one ref-pointer to the next.

Last thing about

> By default, function arguments are passed by value (so that if the value of the argument within the function is changed, it does not get changed outside of the function).

that comes from php documentaion.

When here is written `passed by value` it means, how it will work.
But in the real process, it will copied in the moment when it is manipulated.
so it is `passed by ref` but act like `passed by value` and only objects will be always an reference until `clone`.

To keep the most important Infos in this answer:

> For one thing, header("Refresh: 3; URL=" + LoginController::HOME_URL);
>   you're trying to concatenate with a + which in PHP it's a dot that
>   needs to be used. You seem to be coming from a C background, hence the
>   error.

Thanks to Fred -ii-

Comment: Don't forget about all the `header("Refresh: 3; URL=" + LoginController::HOME_URL);` [as stated in comments.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42722369/class-objects-are-passed-by-value#comment72564576_42722369)

Comment: @Fred-ii-  Dont know. I was just pointing to the `Class objects are passed by value?` line, to make this part of the O clear. In a way. :-)

Comment: I'm just saying for future visitors ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- You are free to enhance this. :-) im not here for points at all.

Comment: @Fred-ii- How about merging you stuff with that from RiggsFolly. I thing that would be the answer to the question. I was just jumping around ref-count's :-) But i have added your part in my answer.

Comment: If you're asking me to post an answer, be it regular or wiki; thanks but I'm pretty much done with doing that now. I'm just here to give a helping hand in questions/answers now. I feel I'm more useful that way, but that's just me. Thanks for adding that part; I'd upvote but I'm out of them right now. I'll be happy to upvote once I can though :-)